# Input type text field become a multiline in Html

Tags: php, html

i want a text box in my html page , But  i would like to it become a multi line text box . Is it possible in html ? i don't want to use Textarea ,,

Comment: Just for the sake of interest: why not use textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TEXTAREA` tag:

```
<textarea>This is a multi-line box</textarea>
```

You could use jQuery to replace a `textbox` with a `textarea`:

```
$(".swap").click(function(){
  var textArea = $("<textarea></textarea>");
  var textBox  = $(":text[name='message']");
  $(textBox).replaceWith(textArea);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea></textarea>`

See here for details: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp

--
Edit: Oh sorry, you meant a text input. In that case, as responded in the other answer: no, you can't make it multiline but you can swap it for a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that in order for your site to be wcag compliant it should function correctly with JavaScript disabled. This might be an issue concerning the textArea jquery swap approach.

The textarea is to all intents a multiline textbox. The only difference being that it doesn't have a max length property which can be taken care of with a server side validation anyway.

Can you provide more detail on why you cannot use the textarea and perhaps you will get a more suitable answer?